# How to get a value from an ejs file and send it to app.js in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am currently learning NodeJs and already using EJS as its template engine. I am now trying to make a simple contact app as my own exercise. The contact list is loaded from a contacts.json file. I have successfully loaded all the files and now I am trying to get the details for each contact. I want to show the detail based on the contact name as its parameters. Here is my code:

app.js

```
app.get('/contact', (request, response) => {
    const contacts = loadContact();
    response.render('contact', {
        title: 'Contact Page',
        layout: 'layouts/main',
        contacts
    });
});

app.get('/contact/:name', (request, response) => {
    const contact = findContact(request.params.name);
    response.render('contact', {
        layout: 'layouts/main',
        contact
    });
});
```

contact.js

```
const { error } = require('console');
const fs = require('fs');

const dirPath = './data';
if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
}

const dataPath = './data/contacts.json';
if (!fs.existsSync(dataPath)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(dataPath, '[]', 'utf-8');
}

const loadContact = () => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync('data/contacts.json', 'utf-8');
    const contacts = JSON.parse(file);
    return contacts;
};

const findContact = (name) => {
    const contacts = loadContact();
    const contact = contacts.find((contact) => contact.name === name);
    return contact;
};

module.exports = { loadContact, findContact };
```

contact.ejs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>My Contact List</h2>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover my-3">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <% if (contacts.length === 0) { %>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger fw-bold" role="alert">
                      Contact Data is Empty
                    </div>
                  <% } %>
                  <% contacts.forEach((c, i) => { i++ %>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row"><%= i++ %> </th>
                      <td><%= c.name %> </td>
                      <td><%= c.phoneNumber %> </td>
                      <td><a href="/contact/<%= c.name %> " class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"><i class="bi bi-info-circle"></i> Details</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }) %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="container mt3">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md8">

                      <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="contactModalLabel"> </h5>
                              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="container-fluid">
                                  <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                      <ul class="list-group">
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name</strong></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Phone Number</strong></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Email</strong></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md">
                                      <ul class="list-group">
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><%= contact.name %> </li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><%= contact.phoneNumber %> </li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><%= contact.email %> </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is that I want this anchor`<a href="/contact/<%= c.name %> " class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"><i class="bi bi-info-circle"></i> Details</a>` to trigger the modal and the modal content is filled with detailed contact based on any value that I pass from here `href="/contact/<%= c.name %> "` to app.js here

```
app.get('/contact/:name', (request, response) => {
    const contact = findContact(request.params.name);
    response.render('contact', {
        layout: 'layouts/main',
        contact
    });
});
```

I can't pass the value I want with this way. Can anyone tell me to do it correctly? Thank you for your help guys

Comment: If you want to display a modal, you're going to have to start writing client-side javascript.

Comment: So you mean I need to use Ajax or Jquery and use DOM?

Comment: Well you don't necessarily need Ajax of Jquery, but without client-side javascript all you can do is render HTML, and not really make dynamic changes on click. At most you can have a user click a link and render a new page.

Comment: I see. I get it now. Thank you so much for your help @Evert